# Getting the status of a stream from FMS in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, flash-media-server

I'm looking for a way to get the status of a stream from Flash Media Server to action script. I need to know if a stream has any publishers/listeners from flex/ActionScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Adobe Flash Media Server Administration API. There are calls that might help you, such as getNetStreams() and get NetStreamStats(). You could try writing a server-side action script class that makes these calls to the admin API, then pushes the results back to your Flex application through a callback on your NetConnection.